# Security code for IOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, security

Currently we are developing a track and trace app for our company. To make this app more secure we would like to to ask the user at first launch for a security code. This security code will most likely be the customer number.

Ones the user sends a request to the server with his trace and trace code the server will check if the security code and the track and trace code are linked.

My question is what would be the best way to store the security code in the app so that the app can ask for it ones a track and trace gets send to the server. We want the user to enter the security code only at first start.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"security code"];
```

would this be an option?

Comment: wouldnt it be saver to store that stuff on your servers and somewhat transmit the unique phone id (or number? or whatsoever) and look it up internally? if no dataset is found ask user for the pin

Comment: A bool is only true/false, you may want a string instead. And if the customer number somewhat secret, you could consider storing in keychain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any secure data you wish to store on the device, I strongly advise you use the Keychain. You can then check for the code's existence within the keychain, and use that if it's available.

See the following documentation below to get you on your feet with the Keychain!

**Keychain Concepts** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9

**How to implement on iOS** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

**Reference** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898

**Sample Project** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797

Comment: Sounds great going to take a look at this.

Comment: Keychain is the answer.. Never use `NSUserDefault` to store sensitive informations.

Answer (score 2):

`user1805901> This security code will most likely be the customer number.`

How guessable is that? You might want to look into a UUID in case of loss. Provide the mapping from UUID to customer number at the server.

`WDUK> For any secure data you wish to store on the device, I strongly advise you use the Keychain.`

In addition to Keychain, you also have to look at `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`, `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock`, `kSecAttrAccessibleAlways`, `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly`, `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly`, and `kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly`.

`kSecAttrAccessibleAlways` and `kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly` are poison, and should not be used since the Keychain can leak the data. See [iOS Keychain Weaknesses](http://sit.sit.fraunhofer.de/studies/en/sc-iphone-passwords-faq.pdf) for details (its gotten better, but its can still be a problem).

`*ThisDeviceOnly` means the secret is not included on a restore to a different device. Its helpful for some Copy/Paste attacks.

And if you don't want the secret on the cloud, I believe the Keychain attributes need to include `com.apple.MobileBackup`. See [Technical Q&A QA1719](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) for details.

Jeff